# Difficulty understand Tkinter mainloop() in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Okay, so I've got a basic window with an EDIT and VIEW button.  As my code stands, EDIT and VIEW both return a message "this button is useless".  I created these under the class "main_window".  I created another class "edit_window" that I'm hoping to call when the EDIT button is clicked.  Essentially, clicking the edit button should change display the new window with buttons ADD and REMOVE. Here's my code so far...what would be the next logical step?

```
from Tkinter import *
#import the Tkinter module and it's methods
#create a class for our program

class main_window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(padx=15,pady=100)

        self.edit = Button(frame, text="EDIT", command=self.edit)
        self.edit.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.view = Button(frame, text="VIEW", command=self.view)
        self.view.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

    def edit(self):
        print "this button is useless"

    def view(self):
        print "this button is useless"

class edit_window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(padx=15, pady=100)

        self.add = Button(frame, text="ADD", command=self.add)
        self.add.pack()

        self.remove = Button(frame, text="REMOVE", command=self.remove)
        self.remove.pack()

    def add(self):
        print "this button is useless"

    def remove(self):
        print "this button is useless"


top = Tk()
top.geometry("500x500")
top.title('The Movie Machine')
#Code that defines the widgets

main = main_window(top)


#Then enter the main loop
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: What don't you understand about mainloop? To me it seems you're looking for [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm), with which you can make edit_window a separate window.

Comment: I might not have explained well enough.  I want the main window to update based on what button you click.  So I don't want to open a new window if I click EDIT, I want the existing window to quite displaying EDIT and VIEW---it should update to display ADD REMOVE in the same manner that it was displaying EDIT VIEW previously.  Make sense?  So I assumed Toplevel would simply open a new window with ADD REMOVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a [`Toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) instead of using a `Frame`:

```
class MainWindow:
    #...
    def edit(self):
        EditWindow()

class EditWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.add = Button(self, text="ADD", command=self.add)
        self.remove = Button(self, text="REMOVE", command=self.remove)
        self.add.pack()
        self.remove.pack()
```

I've changed the class names according to the CapWords convention (see [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)). This is not mandatory, but I recommend you to use it in all your Python projects to keep an uniform style.

Comment: Appreciate the answer!  I'm trying to keep the program running in a single window, though.  Toplevel windows are annoying.  Is there a way to add the buttons ADD REMOVE while removing the buttons EDIT VIEW?  To update the window, so to speak?

Comment: Update: I realized I can hide the root window and force_focus the Toplevel window, so seemingly the window doesn't change.  Thanks for the help!